# MongoDB - dont understand how to loop through collections with a cursor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoid

```
advertisers = db.dbname.find( 'my query which returns things correctly' );
```

I realize now that it returns a cursor to the list of collections.

But I am not sure how to loop through them and get each collection.

I want to try something like this:

```
advertisers.each(function(err, advertiser) {
    console.log(advertiser);
});
```

But that does not work. But I didn't see from searching online how to make it actually work with simple JavaScript.

Then I have this code:

```
var item;

if ( advertisers != null )
{
   while(advertisers.hasNext()) 
   { 
      item = advertisers.next();
   }
}
```

and it gives this error: `SyntaxError: syntax error (shell):1`

Help much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is:

```
var item;
var items = db.test.find();
while(items.hasNext()) {
   item = items.next();
   /* Do something with item */
}
```

There is also the more functional:

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
   /* do something */
});
```

Comment: thanks..I had tried that, but for some reason I was getting an error like this: Tue Jun  5 16:31:08 SyntaxError: syntax error (shell):1
Tue Jun  5 16:31:08 uncaught exception: error hasNext: false

Comment: @Justing I tried that, but it still didn't work for some reason.

Comment: does the collection test have items?  I just pasted the exact code into mongo shell and it worked...

Comment: I just updated my original question with the error checking that I do

Comment: Try to type the code exactly instead of pasting it.  Are you on windows?

Comment: Can `items.hasNext()` and `items.next()` really be used synchronously like that? Seems like they should have `await` in front of them.

Answer (score 1):

One more way to loop through collections is using toArray cursor's method:

```js
var results = db.getCollection('posts').find({}).toArray();

for(var i = 0; i <= results.length -1; i++)
{
    print("Author is:" + results[i].Author);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not showing the stack then I assume your problem is the parameter you are passing to the find function, this parameter has to be a JavaScript object, therefore:

```
var query = {
    key: 'my query which returns things correctly'
}

advertisers = db.dbname.find(query);
advertisers.each (function(err, doc){

    //.... error code not included.....
    console.log(doc);
});
```